# How to get rid in opencms of the CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException when listing WebDAV '__properties' folders?

Tags: opencms

With the standard OpenCms WebDAV config, you can get a `CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException` error when accessing resources via WebDAV.

This is very annoying, because whenever you list the content of any `__properties` folder, OpenCms dumps 36 stacktrace loglines per file in that folder! If you scan your WebDAV dirs often during debugging (see note 1), these logs makes your life harder. (Of course, you could change the log level to something higher than `INFO`, but for me that's not acceptable.)

The issue is easily reproducible: point the browser to the opencms-exported webdav path, and click on any `__properties` dir.

I have found two workarounds, but I'm not really happy with any of them. Perhaps there is a better solution?

---

Notes

<sup>1</sup> I'm debugging some OpenCms modules with NetBeans. I export their sources via OpenCms' WebDAV, and mount them in linux as `davfs`. If I add them to a NetBeans project, it automatically scans this mounted file hierarchy, resulting in OpenCms getting 'berserk' and beginning to overflow my poor console with useless traces. It gets worse, as NetBeans periodically re-scans these directories.

<sup>2</sup> Setting the `content-encoding` property of every possible file and dir to UTF-8 does not help (the stacktrace claims it is missing).

---

My relevant environment and settings:

```
INFO OpenCms version      : 8.0.3
INFO System file.encoding : UTF-8
INFO i18n configuration   : the JVM default locale is "en"
INFO Initializing WebDAV servlet
INFO Initialized param "listings" with value "true"
INFO Initialized param "readonly" with value "false"
INFO Using repository with name "standard"
```

`web.xml` relevant config:

```xml
<servlet>
    <description>
        Creates an access to OpenCms through WebDAV.
    </description>
    <servlet-name>OpenCmsWebDavServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.opencms.webdav.CmsWebdavServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>listings</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>readonly</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>repository</param-name>
      <param-value>standard</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

My `opencms-importexport.xml` relevant config:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository name="standard" class="org.opencms.repository.CmsRepository">
        <params>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperJsp</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlContent</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlPage</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperSystemFolder</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperPropertyFile</param>
        </params>
        <filter type="include">
            <regex>/</regex>
            <regex>/__properties/.*</regex>
            <regex>/sites/.*</regex>
            <regex>/system/</regex>
            <regex>/system/__properties/.*</regex>
            <regex>/system/galleries/.*</regex>
            <regex>/system/modules/.*</regex>
            <regex>/system/workplace/.*</regex>
        </filter>
    </repository>
```

My `opencms-system.xml` relevant config:

```xml
<opencms>
  <system>
    <internationalization>
      <localehandler class="org.opencms.i18n.CmsDefaultLocaleHandler"/>
      <localesconfigured>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>de</locale>
      </localesconfigured>
      <localesdefault>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>de</locale>
      </localesdefault>
      <timezone>GMT+01:00</timezone>
    </internationalization>
```

The stacktrace:

```
01 Aug 2012 18:09:05,607  INFO [.opencms.i18n.CmsLocaleManager: 311] Could not read encoding property for resource "/sites/default/.content/config/__properties/c_0001.html.properties".
org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException: Error reading the property value for property "content-encoding" of resource "/.content/config/__properties/c_0001.html.properties".
    at org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException.createException(CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException.java:71)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDbContext.throwException(CmsDbContext.java:334)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDbContext.report(CmsDbContext.java:286)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsSecurityManager.readPropertyObject(CmsSecurityManager.java:4405)
    at org.opencms.file.CmsObject.readPropertyObject(CmsObject.java:2681)
    at org.opencms.i18n.CmsLocaleManager.getResourceEncoding(CmsLocaleManager.java:305)
    at org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsObjectWrapper.needUtf8Marker(CmsObjectWrapper.java:871)
    at org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsObjectWrapper.getResourcesInFolder(CmsObjectWrapper.java:382)
    at org.opencms.repository.CmsRepositorySession.list(CmsRepositorySession.java:268)
    at org.opencms.webdav.CmsWebdavServlet.renderHtml(CmsWebdavServlet.java:2480)
    at org.opencms.webdav.CmsWebdavServlet.serveResource(CmsWebdavServlet.java:2727)
    at org.opencms.webdav.CmsWebdavServlet.doGet(CmsWebdavServlet.java:1208)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.opencms.webdav.CmsWebdavServlet.service(CmsWebdavServlet.java:2893)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException: Unable to read resource "/.content/config/__properties".
    at org.opencms.db.generic.CmsVfsDriver.readResource(CmsVfsDriver.java:2162)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDriverManager.readResource(CmsDriverManager.java:7293)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDriverManager.readPropertyObjects(CmsDriverManager.java:7110)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDriverManager.readPropertyObject(CmsDriverManager.java:7043)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsSecurityManager.readPropertyObject(CmsSecurityManager.java:4403)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two work arounds:

### Edit the filter regex to exclude the '__properties' dirs.

In `opencms-importexport.xml`:

```xml
   <repository name="webdavrep" class="org.opencms.repository.CmsRepository">
        <params><!-- don't change it --></params>
        <filter type="include">
            <regex>/</regex>
            <regex>/__properties/.*</regex>
            <regex>/sites/((?!__properties).)*</regex>
            <!-- instead of ...
            <regex>/sites/.*</regex>
            -->
            <!-- etc -->
        </filter>
   </repository>
```

(Don't forget to update your `web.xml` to change the webdav repository name.)

### Remove the 'CmsResourceWrapperPropertyFile' from the repository.

In `opencms-importexport.xml`:

```xml
   <repository name="webdavrep" class="org.opencms.repository.CmsRepository">
        <params>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperJsp</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlContent</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlPage</param>
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperSystemFolder</param>
            <!-- Do not publish properties ...
            <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperPropertyFile</param>
            -->
        </params>
        <filter type="include"><!-- don't change it --></filter>
```

(Again, don't forget to update your `web.xml` to change the webdav repository name.)